# How do I take and save a BMP screenshot in SDL 2?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2

Using just a given SDL_Window* and SDL_Renderer*, how can I create and save a screenshot in SDL 2.0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below is a function for saving a screenshot in SDL 2 taken from a library I'm currently writing.

```
bool saveScreenshotBMP(std::string filepath, SDL_Window* SDLWindow, SDL_Renderer* SDLRenderer) {
    SDL_Surface* saveSurface = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* infoSurface = NULL;
    infoSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(SDLWindow);
    if (infoSurface == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create info surface from window in saveScreenshotBMP(string), SDL_GetError() - " << SDL_GetError() << "\n";
    } else {
        unsigned char * pixels = new (std::nothrow) unsigned char[infoSurface->w * infoSurface->h * infoSurface->format->BytesPerPixel];
        if (pixels == 0) {
            std::cerr << "Unable to allocate memory for screenshot pixel data buffer!\n";
            return false;
        } else {
            if (SDL_RenderReadPixels(SDLRenderer, &infoSurface->clip_rect, infoSurface->format->format, pixels, infoSurface->w * infoSurface->format->BytesPerPixel) != 0) {
                std::cerr << "Failed to read pixel data from SDL_Renderer object. SDL_GetError() - " << SDL_GetError() << "\n";
                delete[] pixels;
                return false;
            } else {
                saveSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(pixels, infoSurface->w, infoSurface->h, infoSurface->format->BitsPerPixel, infoSurface->w * infoSurface->format->BytesPerPixel, infoSurface->format->Rmask, infoSurface->format->Gmask, infoSurface->format->Bmask, infoSurface->format->Amask);
                if (saveSurface == NULL) {
                    std::cerr << "Couldn't create SDL_Surface from renderer pixel data. SDL_GetError() - " << SDL_GetError() << "\n";
                    delete[] pixels;
                    return false;
                }
                SDL_SaveBMP(saveSurface, filepath.c_str());
                SDL_FreeSurface(saveSurface);
                saveSurface = NULL;
            }
            delete[] pixels;
        }
        SDL_FreeSurface(infoSurface);
        infoSurface = NULL;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Cheers!
-Neil

Comment: `pixels = NULL;` should be `delete[] pixels;`, otherwise the array is leaked.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using OpenGL with SDL2 you can call [`glReadPixels`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) directly instead of using the info surface and renderer. Here is an example (without error checking).

```
void Screenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h, const char * filename)
{
    unsigned char * pixels = new unsigned char[w*h*4]; // 4 bytes for RGBA
    glReadPixels(x,y,w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    SDL_Surface * surf = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(pixels, w, h, 8*4, w*4, 0,0,0,0);
    SDL_SaveBMP(surf, filename);

    SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
    delete [] pixels;
}
```

Here's the [SDL wiki page](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_CreateContext) with an example of setting up the window and an OpenGL context.

Edit: If you are tempted to copy/paste this snippet, remember to **add some  error checking**

Comment: Thanks for the code sample! It works pretty good after you [invert the surface vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41494487/536172).

Comment: And also take into account the [endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38038504/536172) :)

Answer (score 1):

```
void Screenshot(int x, int y, int w, int h, const char * filename)
{
Uint32 rmask, gmask, bmask, amask;

rmask = 0x000000ff;
gmask = 0x0000ff00;
bmask = 0x00ff0000;
amask = 0xff000000;

unsigned char * pixels = new unsigned char[w*h*4]; // 4 bytes for RGBA
glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

SDL_Surface * surf = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom(pixels, w, h, 8*4, w*4, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
SDL_SaveBMP(surf, filename);

SDL_FreeSurface(surf);
delete [] pixels;
}
```

Comment: Please read the guidelines about how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Specifically, describe your problem, your attempt, and the difficulties with it.